# Microsoft Graph API CallRecord with expanded sessions returns an error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

When I execute a request for a specific callRecord like this it works:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}`

But when I do this I get an error (500):
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}?$expand=sessions`

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-04-14T12:21:34",
            "request-id": "{guid}",
            "client-request-id": "{guid}"
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this doesn't happen for every callRecord though. We started seeing this error in our logging around 2022-04-11T00:24:00Z, now we get thousands of those.

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will update you soon

Comment: I saw no more errors on friday 15/04 and when retrieving the problematic callRecord from above it now works! Everything seems to be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell me how to get value of {id}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an internal issue on Microsoft's side. Everything seems to be fixed.